# Assigning nested variable across different batch files doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface

I have 3 batch files, of which each has a specific functionality, where each could have its own variables, although they could be referencing variables from each other multiple times, e.g. in the code I attached, you can see `specs` variable is set in main, although it references a variable from `cars_specs.cmd`, and this variable is used in a 3rd file `desc_gen.cmd` to generate `desc` which uses both of the variables from the other 2 files, and then I use this variable again in the main file to print it.

These are the batch files I'm using and called from cmd `main bmw`
main.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


call desc_gen
call cars_specs

set /p "car=Enter car model:"

set specs=!%car%_specs!

echo %specs%
echo %desc%

endlocal
```

desc_gen.cmd

```
set desc=This %car% has the following specs: %specs%
```

cars_specs.cmd

```
set bmw_specs=bmw_full_specs
set mer_specs=mercedec_full_specs
```

I was expecting to see this output:
This bmw has the following specs: bmw_full_specs

Although what I'm getting is this:
This  has the following specs:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `desc_gen` at the wrong point. That script relies on the `car` and `specs` variables *already* being set so that it can construct the `desc` variable correctly.

Where you're currently doing it, those variables are not yet created, so the description is set up based on empty variables. The correct place to do it is after you've requested the `car` variable from the user, and set `specs` based on that:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call cars_specs

set /p "car=Enter car model:"

set specs=!%car%_specs!
call desc_gen

echo %specs%
echo %desc%

endlocal
```

The following transcript shows this running:

```
C:\Users\PaxDiablo>main
Enter car model:bmw
bmw_full_specs
This bmw has the following specs: bmw_full_specs

C:\Users\PaxDiablo>main
Enter car model:mer
mercedec_full_specs
This mer has the following specs: mercedec_full_specs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer paxdiablo, but I'm calling the other 2 files from within setlocal and endlocal, and I don't have any calls outside it.

Comment: @AbdElRahmanShahat: apologies, I misunderstood the question, edited answer now contains the solution.